# TensorFlow – Slice at different position for each batch element

Tags: tensorflow

I need to slice a window of constant size for each batch element, but starting at different locations. For example, for windows of length two, I want to be able to do something like:

```
batch = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3],
                     [4, 5, 6]])
window_size = 2
window_starts = tf.constant([1, 0])  # The index from which to start slicing for each batch element.

slice_windows(batch, window_size, window_starts) 

# this should return [[2, 3],
#                     [4, 5]]
```

I won’t know what the window_starts are beforehand (they come from data), so I can’t just enumerate all of the indices I need and use tf.gather_nd.

Furthermore, after doing computations on the windows, I then need to pad them back into place with 0s (so a different amount of padding for each batch element):

```
...computation on windows...

restore_window_positions(windows, window_starts, original_size=3)

# this should return [[0, 2, 3],
#                     [4, 5, 0]]
```